# Android:AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android. I have a problem when i tried to populate values from SQLite database to an AutoCompleteTextView. I got values from the database to a string array via a function **getAllFnames()**[**shown below**]. But AutoCompleteTextView is not showing any suggestions at run time..anybody there to help me.....codes are given below..please check..thank you..(Log Cat is showing some filtering problems!)

```
 public String[] getAllFnames() {

     database=open();
     Fname=new String[1000];
     int i=0;
Cursor cursor = database.query(DbCreation.PATIENT_TABLE,Columns, null, null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          Fname[i]=cursor.getString(1).toString();
          Log.v("DataBaseValues...", Fname[i]);
          cursor.moveToNext();
          i++;
        }

        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return Fname;
}
```

At text view side

```
      Fname=ss.getAllFnames();//here Fname is a string array
             //"ss" is the object of class where method getAllFname()  is placed.
ArrayAdapter<String> fnameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,Fname);

     fnameSearch.setThreshold(1);//fnameSearch is the AutoCompleteTextView

     fnameSearch.setAdapter(fnameAdapter);

     fnameSearch.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Use your array of data in place of Months array. Rather use arraylist in place of array of size 1000. It's more efficient.

public class autocomplete extends Activity {

```
 static final String[] Months = new String[]{
    "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
    "September","October","November","December"
    };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete);

    ArrayAdapter<String> monthArray = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Months);


    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.testAutoComplete);
            textView.setAdapter(monthArray);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fnameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Fname);
```

Try this.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I am seeing here is (Assuming you are getting values from DB)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fnameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list,Fname);
```

Replace it by

```
myAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Fname));
```

Comment: @Anu Please close the question by accepting the correct answer.

Comment: i got answer..can i find any options to close the question...?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method getAllFnames() in the following way

```
   public String[] getAllFnames() {

     database=open();


         Cursor cursor = database.query(DbCreation.PATIENT_TABLE,Columns, null, null, null, null, null);
         if(cursor.getCount() >0){
             String []  Fname=new String[cursor.getCount()];
             int i=0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

           Fname[i]=cursor.getString(0).toString();//+" "+cursor.getString(1).toString();
          Log.v("DataBaseValues...", Fname[i]);

          i++;
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return Fname;
         }
         else return new String[] {};
  }
```

And

```
     String [] Fname=ss.getAllFnames();

      int i=0;
      Log.v("insidichSearchAct..", Fname[i]);

     ArrayAdapter<String> fnameAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.fname_search_list,Fname);
     fnameSearch.setThreshold(1);
     fnameSearch.setAdapter(fnameAdapter);
```

Then i got suggestion values to AutoCompleteTextView Thanx to all experts...